# Finding biggest number using arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

The code is working for the one digit numbers but not working for two or three digit numbers, what should i do >???? i want to do this way only without using math max function.

The problem mainly is that it is considering only first digit of the two digit number. So what can i do so that it can read two digit number as two digits and print the maximum then.

---

A fast response will be appreciated.

```js
document.querySelector('.result').addEventListener('click',function(){

    var val1, val2 , val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8;
    var max = 0;
    
    
    val1 = document.querySelector('#value1').value;
    val2 = document.querySelector('#value2').value;
    val3 = document.querySelector('#value3').value;
    val4 = document.querySelector('#value4').value;
    val5 = document.querySelector('#value5').value;
    val6 = document.querySelector('#value6').value;
    val7 = document.querySelector('#value7').value;
    val8 = document.querySelector('#value8').value;
  
    //console.log(val1);
    
var array = [val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8];

    for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
        if(array[i] > max)
            {
                max = array[i];
            }
    }    




    
    document.getElementById('totalt').value= max;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <div class="outer-block"> 
        <em><h1>Biggest number</h1></em>

      
        <h3>Enter marks</h3>
        <div class="display"> FIRST NUMBER: </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Number 1" class="marks" id="value1">
        <div class="display"> SECOND NUMBER: </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Number 2" class="marks" id="value2">
        <div class="display"> THIRD NUMBER: </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Number 3" class="marks" id="value3">
        <div class="display"> FORTH NUMBER: </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Number 4" class="marks" id="value4">
        <div class="display"> FIFTH NUMBER: </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Number 5" class="marks" id="value5">
        <div class="display"> SIXTH NUMBER: </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Number 6" class="marks" id="value6">
        <div class="display"> SEVENTH NUMBER: </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Number 7" class="marks" id="value7">
        <div class="display"> EIGHTH NUMBER: </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Number 8" class="marks" id="value8">
        
        
        
        
        
        
        <input type="submit" value="GO" class="result">
        <div class="display" id="totale">BIGGEST NUMBER</div>
        <input type="text" id="totalt" class="marks">
 
        
</div>    
    
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: input element values are strings, if you want to compare them like number you need to coerce them to numbers first.

Comment: You need to convert `value` into `number` from `string`. You can use `+` unary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];

//    console.log(Math.max(...array))

let max = '';
array.forEach(x=> {
  if(parseInt(x) > max){
    max = x;
  }
});

console.log(max);
```

You can spread the array as argument to pass into `Math.max` or alternatively as you wished, using a `forEach` loop and parseInt each and every element before doing the checking

Comment: OP doesn't want to use the `max()` function _"i want to do this way only without using math max function"_

Comment: This solution i got but i was trying if it could be possible only by using the for loop and not using math.max

Comment: @djmayank: Sorry I've missed out that point, please have a look at my updated version

Comment: YA this is what i want , *** parseInt ***  thanx guys for help!!

Comment: @djmayank: do mark it as answer if it helps to answer your question, thanks

Comment: ya i was waiting for that only it is saying u can mark only after 5 min. lel